# using Google Maps with CSS Tricks Organic Tabs

Tags: jquery, google-maps, tabs

I am having an issue with trying to implement Google Maps with CSS Tricks Organic Tabs (http://css-tricks.com/organic-tabs/). I fixed the issue of the map not loading correctly when clicking on a tab. But now I am stuck with it throwing the map off center.

I'm trying to set the center of the map when a tab is clicked. Is this possible? Something like this:

```
jQuery('tab-nav li > a').click(function(){
    map.setCenter(point);
});
```

This is where I fixed the problem of it not displaying correctly

```
// Fade in new list on callback
base.$el.find("#"+listID).fadeIn(base.options.speed, function(){
    if(map != undefined && map != null)
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

You can see the problem here: https://www.revival.tv/new/

It only displays the map correctly when loading on that tab: https://www.revival.tv/new/?tab=location

Comment: if you aren't using map controls, why not just use a google static map

Comment: @charlietfl I would like people to be able to move the map around to see nearby streets/freeways

Answer (score 0):

try a setTimeout of 500 or so and it fixed the glitchy behaviour for me. You can also set the center again after redrawing it... e.g. put this just before you return false from the click event in the tabs .js :

```
setTimeout(function() {
                        google.maps.event.trigger( minimap[redrawMapId], 'resize' );
                        minimap[redrawMapId].setZoom( 11 );
                        minimap[redrawMapId].setCenter(myLatLng); 
                    }, 500);
```

minimap[redrawMapId] is simply what "map" was in my code - I had several maps on a page.